Research Topics in Conformal Prediction
My background is in econometrics and soon I'll start to work in my master's thesis. One thing that recently got my attention were uncertainty quantification methods, specifically Conformal Prediction.
One thing that seems particularly cool is that it can be adapted to ensure coverage across specific groups in the covariates or even the labels. Additionally, 'recently', the research community was able to tackle the most limiting assumption, that of exchangeability, meaning it can be applied, for example, to time-series data.
My questions are two-fold (one out of curiosity and the other for personal interest):

What are some real-world scenarios that you've seen Conformal Prediction shine? And if there is some scenario that you'd think it would work but didn't.
And what do you think are some interesting questions yet to be addressed?

Any thoughts or general feedback very welcome! Thanks in advance!
